# Google User Content Javascript api

Tags: jquery, google-api, google-api-client

I try to get user image profile from user. I create ajax request using jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/myusername/@self",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: {},
  success: function (result) {
    image = result.entry.thumbnailUrl;
    name = result.entry.displayName;
  },
  error: function () {
  }
});
```

but I get 405 error message.
When I request the url from the broswer, I get the json object correctly.

Solution with c# .Net also good.
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to `GET` JSON data, you can also use `$.getJSON`. Also, do you have any kind of reference for what you are trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP error 405 says *Method not allowed* and you wrote `type: "get"` in your Ajax request, replace it with `type: "GET"` in your code.